# Tapped-Transformer

Tags: transformer

[image]

I had a question in mind that what changes happens with the current when we change the tapping the of the transformer. Does the kVA rating of the transformer always remains constant or it fluctuates with change in tapping positions? Let me elaborate my question with an example. If I have 24 V on secondary side of a transformer with rated  current as 5 A at full load. Then if I change the tapping to 50%, then the voltage becomes 12 V. What happens to the current, wil it be 10 A to maintain the rating of the transformer or will it be something else.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's the *current* rating of the tap that remains constant, assuming that the wire is all of the same size (gauge). Therefore, the maximum power is proportional to the voltage.

It would be theoretically possible to build a transformer that has heavier wire for the lower taps, but this would be rare, making the transformer larger than necessary if you're going to use the higher-voltage taps.

Comment: So will the current remain constant and  rating of transformer be halved?

Answer (score 0):

while you change the tapping, the only thing going to vary is the turn's ratio. fixed primary turns and variable secondary turns

The turns ratio will effect the output voltage.

Comment: Ok so you mean to say that current will remain fixed at both 12 V and 24V tapping?

Comment: yes, mostly transformers are designed like that... but in some rare cases power (KVA) will be constant and current(A) will vary..

Answer (score 0):

We have custom transformers manufactured with constant VA ratings no matter which tap is used. The manufacturer chooses the appropriate wire size to match the required current for each tap.

Although this results in a more expensive transformer than the conventional winding techniques, the space savings is worth the (small) extra cost.

Comment: You mean kVA remains constant.

Comment: Someone's saying kVA is constant and someone is saying the kVA changes. Who is right?

Comment: @JohnCena Both are right. It depends on how the transformer is physically built. Most transformers will have a constant current rating, but some custom-made ones can have a constant VA rating.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks for the clarification @Dwayne Reid.

Comment: I think that generally current rating is constant to reduce extra expenditure and reduce losses.

Comment: @JonnCena: Both of the terms "VA" and "KVA" are valid, depending on the actual ratings. In the case of the custom transformer that I mentioned, it is a 400 VA transformation. That is equivalent to a rating of 0.4 KVA.

Comment: What mechanism do we use to keep the current constant in transformer even while tapping is changed?

Comment: You don't. Maximum current is determined by many factors - wire size is just one factor.